# what's the return value of unblock assignment in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I found this statement in a verilog source code, I don't know what does it mean?
what is the return value of the unblock assignment? Is it NUMBER_OF_INPUT_WORDS-1 ?

```
assign axis_tready = ((mst_exec_state == WRITE_FIFO) && (write_pointer <= NUMBER_OF_INPUT_WORDS-1));
```

Comment: I consider the <= as an unblock assignment of verilog !  Yes, I am stupid...

Comment: I just realized it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This statement will assign 1/0 to `axis_ready`.

Your code is same like below elaborated code.

```
wire cmp1, cmp2;

assign cmp1 = (mst_exec_state == WRITE_FIFO); // Gives output in 0/1
assign cmp2 = (write_pointer <= NUMBER_OF_INPUT_WORDS-1); // Gives output in 0/1
assign axis_tready = cmp1 & cmp2;
```